# What is the perl equivalent of PHP's preg_quote function?

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I have a string that I want to match within a perl regex pattern, but characters in it may need escaping. In PHP, the function that does this is preg_quote. What is the equivalent in perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match the contents of a variable literally, enclose it in `\Q...\E` quotes, or use the `quotemeta` function. Both of these work:

```
use feature 'say';
my $metachars = "1+2";
my $escaped_metachars = quotemeta $metachars;

local $_ = "1112, 1+2";

say "\\Q...\\E: ",   /(\Q$metachars\E)/;
say "quotemeta: ",   /($escaped_metachars)/;
say "no escaping: ", /($metachars)/;
```

Output:

```
\Q...\E: 1+2
quotemeta: 1+2
no escaping: 1112
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function.